# MySQL bug : sorting by alphabetical order failing

Tags: mysql, sorting, collation, alphabetical

I have a problem with mysql, I need your help please.

[Version MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRD1O.jpg)

I am sorting alphabetically on a column ('label_mission') the sorting is wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM `m1_mission` ORDER BY `label_mission` ASC
```

Sorting works from the letter A -> T

but Mysql inverts the letter U and the letter V

[Result sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLcc6.jpg)

does anyone have an idea please?

If you want to test the sort here is the code of my MySQL table:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
--
-- Hôte : 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Généré le : sam. 25 juin 2022 à 11:17
-- Version du serveur : 5.7.36
-- Version de PHP : 7.4.26

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de données : `uniq3`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `m1_mission`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `m1_mission`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `m1_mission` (
  `pk_mission` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label_mission` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `processus` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_mission`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci;

--
-- Déchargement des données de la table `m1_mission`
--

INSERT INTO `m1_mission` (`pk_mission`, `label_mission`, `processus`) VALUES
(1, 'PRE-OP', 'PR1'),
(2, 'ESQ', 'PR1'),
(3, 'APS', 'PR1'),
(4, 'APD', 'PR1'),
(5, 'AVP', 'PR1'),
(6, 'PRO', 'PR1'),
(7, 'DCE', 'PR2'),
(8, 'ACT', 'PR2'),
(9, 'DET', 'PR3'),
(10, 'VISA', 'PR3'),
(11, 'EXE', 'PR3'),
(12, 'AOR', 'PR3'),
(13, 'OPC', 'PR3'),
(14, 'PC', 'PR1'),
(15, 'TOPO', 'PR1'),
(20, 'HYDRAU', 'PR1'),
(21, 'G1-PGC', 'PR1'),
(22, 'G1-ES', 'PR1'),
(23, 'G2-AVP', 'PR1'),
(24, 'G2-PRO', 'PR1'),
(25, 'G2-ACT/DCE', 'PR2'),
(26, 'G3', 'PR3'),
(27, 'G4', 'PR3'),
(28, 'G5', 'PR1'),
(29, 'P-R1', 'PR1'),
(30, 'P-R2', 'PR2'),
(31, 'P-R3', 'PR3'),
(32, 'P-M1', 'PM1'),
(33, 'P-M2', 'PM2'),
(34, 'P-M3', 'PM3'),
(35, 'P-S1', 'PS1'),
(36, 'P-S2', 'PS2'),
(37, 'P-S3', 'PS3'),
(38, 'P-S4', 'PS4'),
(39, 'P-S5', 'PS5'),
(40, 'P-S6', 'PS6'),
(41, 'EE ( ÉTUDES ENVIRONNEMENTALES )', 'PR1'),
(42, 'EI ( ÉTUDES D\'IMPACTS )', 'PR1'),
(43, 'FAISABILITÉ', 'PR1'),
(44, 'DIAG', 'PR1'),
(45, 'PERMIS D\'AMÉNAGER', 'PR1'),
(46, 'EP', 'PR1'),
(47, 'SYN', 'PR3'),
(48, 'SUP', 'PR1'),
(49, 'ECO', 'PR1'),
(50, 'DOS', 'PR1'),
(51, 'MC1', 'PR1'),
(52, 'MC2', 'PR1'),
(53, 'MC3', 'PR1'),
(54, 'MC4', 'PR1'),
(55, 'MISSIONS COMPLÉMENTAIRES', 'PR1'),
(56, 'MC5', 'PR1'),
(57, 'MC6', 'PR1'),
(58, 'MC7', 'PR1'),
(59, 'MC8', 'PR1'),
(60, 'MC9', 'PR1'),
(61, 'MC10', 'PR1'),
(62, 'PHASE 1', 'PR1'),
(63, 'PHASE 2', 'PR1'),
(64, 'PHASE 3', 'PR1'),
(65, 'PRO-DCE', 'PR2'),
(66, 'GPA', 'PR3'),
(67, 'OPR', 'PR3'),
(68, 'MOB', 'PR1'),
(69, 'OAD', 'PR1'),
(70, 'DPC', 'PR1'),
(71, 'MISE AU POINT DES MARCHES', 'PR2'),
(72, 'SSI', 'PR1'),
(73, 'USA', 'PR3');
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Can you share the sorting code you mention in your post?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `m1_mission` ORDER BY `label_mission` ASC

Comment: A quick google search: "Note that in the ucs2_roman_ci and utf8_roman_ci collations, I and J compare as equals, and U and V compare as equals" from http://www.yaldex.com/mysql_manual/ch10s10.html and also: https://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_roman_ci.html

Comment: thank you for your reply.

So to solve my problem I have to change Character Sets and Collations

Comment: You only need to change collation.

Comment: I changed the collation:

utf8_roman_ci -> ascii_general_ci

(https://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.ascii_general_ci.html)

the sorting problem persists

Comment: How did you change it? You can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE m1_mission;` after you change the collation and check if all of the required collation has been changed.

Comment: Try collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: problem solved : the collation : ascii_general_ci (collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.ascii_general_ci.html)

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit the world "solved" into the question.

Answer (score 0):

In ancient Latin ("roman"), "U" and "V" were the same.  Unless you are working with such, I would recommend not using any "roman" `COLLATION`.

The latest available Unicode standard is embodied (in MySQL 5.7) in `utf8_unicode_520_ci`.  I suggest you change (via `ALTER`) the column definitions to use that.  That Collation will probably do a better job on French accents.

Here is a chart for `CHARACTER SET utf8`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

If you have already changed the table to "ascii", then accents are probably lost.  If not, then

```
ALTER TABLE m1_mission
    CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci;
```

utf8mb4 is also good and would allow for Emoji and some obscure Chinese characters.